# What is the DMZ in networking?

Tags: networking, dmz

What is the DMZ in networking? Is it all about having Firewall to isolate servers, data, or users from the outside boundary of the network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DMZ is a Demilitarized Zone.

This is usually a subnet which bypasses the firewall, and allows direct connection to the internet. This is used when outside applications need to access a server, or another device inside an intranet.

The purpos of this is so that in the event of a security breech, an attacker can only access devices in the DMZ, and nothing else on the same intranet.

Comment: I up voted your answer because its helpful but I also voted to close this question  because it doesn't belong here

Comment: I also voted to close, but figured I could still help the OP before it got shut down. :D